# How to merge two group by attribute

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset with  10 variables 
The last variable is a factor variable with levels 1-2-3-4-5

My prof thinks that the units that has the attribute 1 and 3 May be merged in a new factor levels bevande they May be the dame.
How can I see if those units has the same structure in the data?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question: Right now, Variable 1 has five levels [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Your professor thinks you can collapse levels 1 and 3 together, which would mean you have four levels [2, 4, 5, 1&3]. Your question is what test can tell you if you can collapse those levels into one?

Comment: Yes it is, how can I see if this merge is right to be done?